# Essential Self Adjointness of Laplacian on $(-\infty,\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

What conditions are necessary to have the negative Laplacian, $-\Delta$, self adjoint (or essentially self adjoint) when defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$?

I only have experience studying boundary value problems where conditions on our functions are specified at the boundary. eg if we take the Hilbert Space $L^2[0,1]$ and the differential operator $Lf=-i\dfrac{df}{dx}$, we must have that the domain of $L$ are smooth functions with periodic boundary conditions $f(0)=f(1)$ to ensure that $L$ is essentially self adjoint

If we take $-\Delta$ and the a domain runs from $(-\infty,\infty)$, how do we pose conditions on our function space to have $-\Delta$ essentially self adjoint?
thanks